# Sequence and Trigger, PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, sequence

I'm using Oracle for the first time, much more used to sql server and their identitys. But now I'm trying to use a sequence and trigger. But keep getting this error I can't fix.

```
identifiers may not start with any ASCII character other than
       letters and numbers.  $#_ are also allowed after the first
       character.  Identifiers enclosed by doublequotes may contain
       any character other than a doublequote.  Alternative quotes
       (q'#...#') cannot use spaces, tabs, or carriage returns as
       delimiters.  For all other contexts, consult the SQL Language
       Reference Manual.
```

Can anyone help fix it, here is my code.

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE' CREATE SEQUENCE stagechardata_stagecharid
     START WITH 1 
     INCREMENT BY 1;';  

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE' CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER stagechardata_stagecharid_TRG
     BEFORE INSERT 
     ON stage_char_data
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
     IF NEW.stage_char_id IS NULL THEN
        SELECT stagechardata_stagecharid.NEXTVAL INTO NEW.stage_char_id
          FROM DUAL;
          END IF;
     END;';
```

Comment: Why are you using `execute immediate`? Do you have a reason you need to create these dynamically from PL/SQL rather than normal SQL? (As it is, you shouldn't have a semicolon at the end of the first dynamic statement, and your `new` references are missing a colon, but those are not causing that error). Can you show the rest of the PL/SQL block or script?

Comment: Remove the `;` at the end for the `create sequence` statement. It is not needed for regular SQL statements when using `execute immediate`, only when creating PL/SQL procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Long shot, but looks like you're missing a space after IMMEDIATE and before the quote that starts the statement.

Comment: Thanks, that's how I had it originally though, and had no luck.

Comment: Blake, can you try typing the statements themselves (no execute immediate) into whatever you use to manually interact with the DB? I'm trying in SQL Fiddle and seems to be ok. Getting error that table does not exist but that means the syntax check works.

Comment: When I do that, it actually compiles but then I recieve an error that states. Bind Variable "NEW" is NOT DECLARED.

Answer (score 0):

A sequence is an object which contains SQL satements, but doesn't store data.
Triggers are SQL blocks that execute when a manipulation occurs on a table.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no visible reason to use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. Is there any invisible? It looks like you should just remove it and execute these statements directly in the SQL mode.

Next, it looks like you forgot to use colon: NEW.stage_char_id IS NULL should be :NEW.stage_char_id IS NULL and so on.